# Auto populate dropdown in list

Tags: 2013, list, dropdown

probably an easy one, but I can not get it to work.

I have a list with two columns:

1. Title (Single line of text)
2. Team (Choice - Dropdown)

[image]

I want to **preset** the "Team" column via a URL-String. I don't want to do it afterwards with an Workflow.

I tried: `http://sp13/lists/listname/NewForm.aspx?Team=Finance`

**In the end, I need it auto populated via an button from different team sites, preset with their team.**

Any ideas would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this JavaScript code in your newForm.aspx page in SEWP:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("your dropdown control's id").value = getParameterByName('Team');
}
        window.onload = myFunction;

        function getParameterByName(name) {
    var url = window.location.href;
    name = name.replace(/[\[\]]/g, "\\$&");
    var regex = new RegExp("[?&]" + name + "(=([^&#]*)|&|#|$)"),
        results = regex.exec(url);
    if (!results) return null;
    if (!results[2]) return '';
    return decodeURIComponent(results[2].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}
        </script>
```

Comment: I guess even more easy, how to get the dropdown control's id?

Comment: You can get it using firebug in FF.

Comment: @Dikesh, just one suggestion: for this scenario the  SEWP (Script Editor Webpart) is better. Actually the SEWP is generally better for HTML, CSS and JS. CEWP is better for adding rich **content** to the page.

Comment: Anybody faced issue with this in IE11? It's working fine in Chrome. It's extracting the value correctly from URL, but .value is just not setting in IE. No errors either.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this. Get the value of query string using `GetUrlKeyValue` and then use javascript/jquery to set the selected dropdown value.

```
$(document).ready(function () {    
    var dropDownValue = GetUrlKeyValue('Team');
    if (dropDownValue) {
        $("select[title='Team']").children("option").each(function () {
            if ($(this).text() == dropDownValue) {
                $(this).attr('selected', 'selected');
            }
        });
    }
});
```

See this for more info:
http://www.sharepointnadeem.com/2014/10/sharepoint-pre-populate-lookup-field-in.html

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way your `setTeam` function can look like:

```
function setTeam(ctx) {

    // Set the default value of the drop-down field from query string.
    ctx.CurrentFieldValue = GetUrlKeyValue('Team');

    // Return the default rendering function for choice fields.
    return SPFieldChoice_Edit(ctx);
}
```

---

#### Notes

- There are no IF statements required because the `GetUrlKeyValue` function always returns an empty string if something is wrong, thus setting the drop-down field to nothing which is the default value anyway.
- If you want to make sure this code works for cases where the `Team` paramater in the query string is lowercase (`team`) or uppercase (`TEAM`) or random (`tEaM`), then use replace `GetUrlKeyValue('Team')` with `GetUrlKeyValue('Team', true, null, true);`.